# Ext JS: Getting a specific row's action column

Tags: gridview, extjs, row, extjs4.2

I have a grid that contains an action column for each row. This action column is an edit icon, and when a user clicks the edit icon, I'm kicking off some websocket events, which will eventually trickle down to other users currently connected to the app. What I want to do is grey out this edit icon for the other users. All of that code is working except: I have no idea how I can access the actual row's action column object.

I can access it by using the grid's view and grabbing that individual node, then setting some sort of CSS, something like this:

```
var rowHtml = this.getView().getNode(index);
if (rowHtml) {
  var rowDom = Ext.fly(rowHtml);
  if (rowDom) {
    rowDom.down('.someclass').removeCls('enabled').addCls('disabled');
  }
}
```

That should work, but I also want to update the tooltip, and in general, I just want to be able to access this element.

So, I guess the main question is, when this action column gets created, is it created as a button or some other Ext JS element? The API states that the [defaultType](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-defaultType) for child components is a **gridcolumn**, but I imagine that's not what this action column really is? Also, is there an easy way of accessing this item as an Ext JS class?

**Edit**: And I have seen the following threads, but they deal more with rendering the rows... my rows are already rendered:

[Hide Icon in Action Column for Particular Row](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?113590-Hide-icon-in-action-column-for-particular-row)

[How to Disable Action Column Item for a Single Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544482/how-to-disable-action-column-item-for-a-single-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided against removing and adding a class.  I'm currently doing it a similar way as described above, but like this:

```
var rowHtml = this.getView().getNode(index);
if (rowHtml) {
  var rowDom = Ext.fly(rowHtml);
  if (rowDom) {
    rowDom.down('.someclass').hide();  // or show, based on some other logic
  }
}
```

I went with hiding/showing because if I just edit the CSS, the action icon can still be clicked.  By hiding/showing, we get rid of that possibility.  It's not ideal, but it works as a quick hack.

Comment: So the only problem I have with my solution is that hiding does not stay set if the view refreshes... I've tried using `Ext.get` instead of `Ext.fly`, but no matter what, when the view refreshes, the icon shows back up... what I need to happen is that the icon's HTML gets set when I use the hide method, so when the view refreshes, it sees the HTML as hidden. Any suggestions?

Comment: I eventually abandoned this approach and went with using the `getClass` method for an ActionColumn's [items](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-items).  Related to my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229168/ext-js-saving-dom-manipulation-of-a-grid-row/22229919#22229919).