# How to disable Delete icon in Extjs grid

Tags: extjs

I have a sample code from extjs, the action is part of multi column of an column where I have edit, delete, duplicate. I want to disable the delete icon based on another field value. I have an another column called IS_USED which returns true/false. The delete button should be disable if IS_USED is true. 
I tried to write the **handler** within **action** but is not working.
I am new in extjs, any help or workaround is appreciable.

```
action: {
  iconCls: 'x-icon-cross-on',
  text:  terms.del,
  url:   url.destroy,
  useAjax: true,
  confirm: terms.confirm,
  handler: function(grid, record, action, domEl, response) {
    if ( !response.success) {
      test.ui.Msg.flash(response.message, test.ui.Msg.ERR);
      javascript.scroll(0,0);
    } else {
      test.ui.Msg.success(response.message);
      grid.getStore().reload();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable action column item for a single row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544482/how-to-disable-action-column-item-for-a-single-row)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is just bind the "disabled" property to the button directly based on the record value.
first, set viewModel:true to the grid.

```
{
   xtype: 'grid',
   //add this below
   itemConfig:{
     viewModel:true
   },
   //....others props like columns, with,etc....
```

and the last, in your button add this:

```
action: {
  iconCls: 'x-icon-cross-on',
  //add this
  bind:{
        disabled:"{record.IS_USED}"  //the logic is placed here
  },
  //.....other props....
```

You can also bind any other bindable properties as like hidden, text, etc by using this trick.

Hope this can help you.